# openlayer en firefox no funciona me funciona Geolocation

Tags: openlayers

Tengo el siguiente problema estoy usando el openlayer 5.3.0 y hoy me dejo de funcionar la función   Geolocation en firefox pero en el chrome anda. 
Si ingreso en la documentacion de openlayer donde estan los ejemplos, en  firefox no anda , **muestra lo siguiente Unknown error acquiring position**.

Pero en chrome funciona bien .
Que debería hacer?
Gracias

Comment: OpenLayers es una api en constante actualizacion y que aun le faltan muchas cosillas, no he visto dicho error, porque jamas utilizo firefox. Pero de seguro que te da algun error en consola, deberias de mostrarlo ya que tal asi como esta tu pregunta podria ser cerrada.

Comment: podrias mostrar tu codigo

Comment: geolocation.on('change:position', function() {                var coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();var cord = btnToUTM_OnClick (coordinates[0],coordinates[1]);  
             
               // console.log("coordenadas"+prueba[0],prueba[1]);
             document.getElementById('form1:coordenasXY').value = cord;
             obtenerUbicacion2();
               zoomtoPoint(cord[0],cord[1]);
                       
        
              });

Answer (score 0):

```
        function obtenerUbicacion(){


                             var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
                                    // enableHighAccuracy must be set to true to have the heading value.
                                    trackingOptions: {
                                      enableHighAccuracy: true
                                    },
                                    projection: view.getProjection()
                                  });


                                  geolocation.on('change:position', function() {
                                    var coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
                                    var cord = btnToUTM_OnClick (coordinates[0],coordinates[1]);        

                                   // console.log("coordenadas"+prueba[0],prueba[1]);
                                    document.getElementById('form1:coordenasXY').value = cord;
                                    obtenerUbicacion2();
                                    zoomtoPoint(cord[0],cord[1]);


                                  });
                            }
```